# Docker | awslogs driver | Setting meaning stream name

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm telling containerd to use awslogs using `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file as proposed in the documentation in https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/awslogs/

By default, the aws stream name is set to a randomly generated container-id which is meaningless when you list the streams inside a group.

awslogs driver has an option to set awslogs-stream to a specific name but that won't satisfy my needs since I want different containers to use different streams.

I guess what I want to do is to tell docker to compose the stream-id from the image name and the container-id, but I couldn't find an option for that.

Theoretically, I can set the stream name directly in the `docker run` command, but that is not good enough because I use Kubernetes to launch those containers so I'm not sure how to set the stream_name from the application yml file.

Any ideas how to accomplish my needs?

Comment: According to https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/15478 there is no option to pass log-driver options from Kubernetes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, there's no sign of `--log-opt` being implemented into Kubernetes, since dockerd is deprecated.

Instead of specifying the `awslogs-stream` have you tried to set a `tag`?

- Check this **[Use Awslogs With Kubernetes 'Natively'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55609398/use-awslogs-with-kubernetes-natively)** as it may fit perfectly to your needs.

From Docker documentation link you posted:

> Specify  `tag`  as an alternative to the  `awslogs-stream`  option.  `tag`  interprets Go template markup, such as  `{{.ID}}`,  `{{.FullID}}`  or  `{{.Name}}`  `docker.{{.ID}}`.
>   See the  [tag option documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/log_tags/)  for details on all supported template substitutions.

*The other viable approach is using a sidecar container daemon to process the logs and then forward to awslogs but `tag` is a cleaner, simplier solution.*

Here's the process with the fluentd:

> **[How to Send Kubernetes Logs to AWS Cloudwatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46469076/how-to-send-kubernetes-logs-to-aws-cloudwatch)**